# dynamically getting all image resource id in an array

Tags: android

there are many images in drawable foder so instead manually creating array of all image resource ids , i want to get all images dynamically of drawable folder  in array.
currently i m using this code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
    {
            int imageKey = getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);  
            image.setId(imgId);
            image.setImageResource(imageKey);    
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            viewFlipper.addView(image, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            imgId++;
        }
```

but in that code i need to manually edit the image name to get the resource id but i want to get all image with any name..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can Use `Reflection` to achieve this.

import the `Field` class

`import java.lang.reflect.Field;`

and then write this in your code

```
Field[] ID_Fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {
    try {
        resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`resArray[]` now holds references to all the drawables in your application.

Comment: thank you very much bro... its working now correctly but it also fetches the icon of application .. is dat any work around for it?

Comment: it simply gets all the drawable Ids which includes the icon. You are going to have to find out a way to exclude it in your logic(iterator/loop).

Comment: just exclude them when you traverse through the list

Comment: and with `getName()` you can get All resources property name. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Well, If your image names are img1, img2 and so on, then you can create a variable like

```
String url = "drawable/"+"img"+i;

int imageKey = getResources().getIdentifier(url, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

you can also replace your getPackageName() method by your package name like "com.android.resource"

 Simply,the general function is

```
public int getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```