# How to initialize an Integer array with R.drawables (Images) using for loop or directory in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-drawable

I have this array of drawables:

```
Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.celeb_0, R.drawable.celeb_1,
            R.drawable.celeb_2, R.drawable.celeb_3, R.drawable.celeb_4,
            R.drawable.celeb_5, R.drawable.celeb_6, R.drawable.celeb_7,
            R.drawable.celeb_8, R.drawable.celeb_9, R.drawable.celeb_10,
            R.drawable.celeb_11, R.drawable.celeb_12, R.drawable.celeb_13,
            R.drawable.celeb_14, R.drawable.celeb_15, R.drawable.celeb_16,
            R.drawable.celeb_17, R.drawable.celeb_18, R.drawable.celeb_19,
            R.drawable.celeb_20, R.drawable.celeb_21, R.drawable.celeb_22,
            R.drawable.celeb_23, R.drawable.celeb_24, R.drawable.celeb_25,
            R.drawable.celeb_26, R.drawable.celeb_27, R.drawable.celeb_28,
            R.drawable.celeb_29, R.drawable.celeb_30, R.drawable.celeb_31,
            R.drawable.celeb_32, R.drawable.celeb_33, R.drawable.celeb_34,
            R.drawable.celeb_35, R.drawable.celeb_36, R.drawable.celeb_37,
            R.drawable.celeb_38, R.drawable.celeb_39, R.drawable.celeb_40,
            R.drawable.celeb_41, R.drawable.celeb_42, R.drawable.celeb_43,
            R.drawable.celeb_44, R.drawable.celeb_45, R.drawable.celeb_46,
            R.drawable.celeb_47, R.drawable.celeb_48, R.drawable.celeb_49};
```

I want to replace the above code with some way of reading all the images in a specific drawable folder and inserting them into mThumbIds

or replace it with something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     mThumbIds[i] =R.drawable.celeb_i; // i is a variable in R.drawable.celeb_i
 }
```

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: i don't think it will work.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I want the initialization of mThumbIds to be more dynamic and not static

Comment: @Waqleh : if `mThumvIds` size if not static then use Integer ArrayList instead of Array

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK my issue is not with the size being dynamic, my issue is inserting **R.drawable.celeb_i** being dynamic as you can see the i is a variable.

Comment: you can not do this because  `mThumbIds[i] =R.drawable.celeb_i;` line will show error no resource `R.drawable.celeb_i`

Comment: @Waqleh: see [dynamically getting all image resource id in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274891/dynamically-getting-all-image-resource-id-in-an-array) may help

Comment: in `R.java` file hexadecimal value for each resource will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
         mThumbIds[i] = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("celeb_"+String.valueOf(i), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
    }
```