# How to change images from mipmap folder dynamically without "direct description" in code?

Tags: android, mipmaps

I have a lot of images (more than 200) with various sizes in mipmap folders, and I need to set images in ImageView dynamically... but how to do this without "direct description" in my code of that R.mipmap.*int files? 
There are flag images in mipmap folders, and my object has it's own String field "flagCountry" which consists of two characters. Names of flags in mipmap folders consist of same characters. So, that's a trouble - how to dynamically set **setImageResource(R.mipmap.XXX)** from flagCountry String variable?
I'm thinking that decision in "reflection", but how is it possible? )) Please help

Comment: Check this link might help [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274891/dynamically-getting-all-image-resource-id-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to find the integer id for a resource given its name.  It's like reflection for android resources.

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("XXX", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Or something along those lines.  This assumes the code is in an activity.  Then you can call `setImageResource(id)` with that id.

Comment: hello, i cant use it with mipmap.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Doug, you can use Resources.getIdentifier() to find the integer id for a resource given its name. But you said you wanted the resource from mipmap. So do a simple change. Change the word "drawable" to "mipmap", and you'll get the image from mipmap. The changed code:

```
int id = getBaseContext()getResources().getIdentifier("XXX", "mipmap", getBaseContext().getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(id);
```