# Android - changing the file played in mediaplayer dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play sounds dynamically.

I have a resource directory that I have created under res folder that is called "raw". this directory contains mp3 files.

What I want to do is to make an Array with all the files names, and when a button is clicked the next mp3 int the next index will be loaded to the mediaplayer and will be playable.

I have found this code for using mediaplayer

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Context context = this;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
                } mp.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });
}
}
```

but I can't seem to find the way to set track switching by Array with using the song name on the i index.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. I have set all the files names in the raw directory with the same name pattern, got each file resource id by its name and loaded it to the player.

```
Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle
    String url = "song" +index;
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("raw/");
    Integer resIdSound = res.getIdentifier (url,  "raw", this.getPackageName());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resIdSound);
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resIdSound);
        } mp.start();
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Comment: An excellent way to instantiate the res folder, and get files by resource id. 
But you re-create the mp before testing so it never returns true for isPlaying().  So, it plays the file on top of itself, for every time that function is run.
I changed the mp to a (null) class parameter, and do a null test before creating it. Then on stop click, I set mp to null again. 
That works as a toggle. 
Again, the first part of this is extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you please why we need to release the mediaPlayer, as like ExoPlayer just replace the URL.

Answer (score 1):

1.Basing on this source:

[dynamically getting all image resource id in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274891/dynamically-getting-all-image-resource-id-in-an-array)

you can try to write this kind of code:

```
Field[] fields= R.raw.class.getFields();
int[] resArray = new int[fields.length];
for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    try {
        resArray[i] = fields[i].getInt(null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and `resArray[]` will contain all the ids that you have in your `raw` folder.

2.If you want to use file names you can use [int getIdentifier (String name, 
                String defType, 
                String defPackage)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method from `Resources` class.

3.If you want to use files from external storage you can easily create `Media Player` instance using file path (remember about permissions)