# I want to iterate mipmap folder to get all the images from mipmap in android

Tags: java, android

I want to iterate mipmap folder to get all the available images from mipmap in android (java),
Suppose I have 10 images(all have a different naming convention, like abc.jpg, pqrst.png ...) in the mipmap folder and I want all these images from this folder programmatically and set it to the ImageView.
I want something like that, all the method names are imaginary:

```
for (int i = 0, i < mipmap.size; i++) {
    final int resourceId;

        resourceId = getResourceIdOfImage(mipmap[i]);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        imageView.setImageResource(resourceId);

        linearLayout.addView(imageView);

    }
```

Comment: Does this will help You https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275199/4211264 ?

Comment: But I want images from mipmap folder not the drawable folder

Comment: Can't you use R.mipmap.class.getFields() in place of R.drawable.class.getFields()

Comment: It gives an error that mipmap() is private